# preg_replace remove parameter variable

Tags: php, url, preg-replace

Want to remove `p2`variable from url string, below are 3 cases if `case 3` also remove `?` sign.

case 1: `http://www.domain.com/myscript.php?p1=xyz&p2=10&p3=ghj`
result: `http://www.domain.com/myscript.php?p1=xyz&p3=ghj`

case 2: `http://www.domain.com/myscript.php?p2=10&p3=ghj`
result: `http://www.domain.com/myscript.php?p3=ghj`

case 3: `http://www.domain.com/myscript.php?p2=10`
result: `http://www.domain.com/myscript.php`

Want to achieve result with single preg_replace expression.

Comment: Did you see my answer on you 1st question about this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14432731/php-reload-page-with-updated-query-string#14432901

Comment: I've incorporated your idea into my answer, no need to put answers inside the question itself :)

Comment: Thanks Sean, that was a different approach from my end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use regular expressions when dealing with URL values. It's much easier (and safer) to handle them as a URL instead of plain text.

This could be one way to do it:

1. Split the url first and parse the query string
2. Take the parameter out
3. Rebuild the url

The below code is an example of such an algorithm:

```
// remove $qs_key from query string of $url
// return modified url value
function clean_url_qs($url, $qs_key)
{
    // first split the url in two parts (at most)
    $parts = explode('?', $url, 2);

    // check whether query string is passed        
    if (isset($parts[1])) {
      // parse the query string into $params
      parse_str($parts[1], $params);

      // unset if $params contains $qs_key
      if (array_key_exists($qs_key, $params)) {
          // remove key
          unset($params[$qs_key]);
          // rebuild the url
          return $parts[0] . 
              (count($params) ? '?' . http_build_query($params) : '');
      }
    }
    // no change required
    return $url;
}
```

Test code:

```
echo clean_url('http://www.domain.com/myscript.php?p1=xyz&p2=10&p3=ghj', 'p2'), "\n";
echo clean_url('http://www.domain.com/myscript.php?p2=10&p3=ghj', 'p2'), "\n";
echo clean_url('http://www.domain.com/myscript.php?p2=10', 'p2'), "\n";
```

Answer (score 1):

Found this in one of my old projects (a bit of shitcode, but...), may help you:

```
$unwanted_param = 'p2';
$s = 'http://www.domain.com/myscript.php?p1=xyz&p2=10&p3=ghj';
$s = parse_url($s);
$params = explode('&', $s['query']);
$out_params = array();
foreach ($params as $key => &$param) {
    list($name, $value) = explode('=', $param);
    if ($unwanted_param == $name) {
        unset($params[$key]);
    } else {
        $out_params[$name] = $value;
    }
}

$query = '?' . http_build_query($out_params);

$result = $s['scheme'] . '://' . $s['host'] . $s['path'] . $query;

var_dump($result);
```

Comment: Hint: use [`parse_str`](http://us.php.net/parse_str) instead of exploding the query manually.

Comment: @DCoder, thanks! That's an old part of code - I was young and stupid :)

Answer (score 0):

Using preg_replace, something like

```
$url = preg_replace('!([\?&]p2=[^&\?$]+)!i', '', $url);
```

However, personally I'd do the following

```
if (strpos($url, '?') !== false) {
    list($domain, $qstring) = explode('?', $url, 2);
    parse_str($qstring, $params);
    if (isset($params['p2'])) {
        unset($params['p2']);
    }
    $qstring = !empty($params) ? '?' . http_build_query($params) : '';
    $url = $domain . $qstring;
}
```